# More than one modul per file - RequireJS and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm now using Backbone without RequireJS and I'd like to rewrite whole my app to utilize RequireJS benefits. Only thing that holds me back is the notion that I will have move each Backbone's Model/View/Collection into separated file to create modules. I would prefer to have more than only one module per file, so the relations for example between linked Models and Views could stay more evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one instances in one module:

```
define(function ( require ) {

    var FirstModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Logic
    });

    var SecondModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Logic
    });

    return {
        first: FirstModel,
        second: SecondModel
    };

});
```

And then simply use them:

```
define(function ( require ) {

    var myModels = require( 'path/to/module' );

    // use myModels.first and myModels.second here

});
```

Comment: And is it possobile to do the same with Views?